# Haskell: IOArray is too slow when reading and writing a lot

Tags: haskell, multidimensional-array

I wrote a small code in Haskell. Could you give a solution to improve performance?

- Input: `Height` and `Width` of a grid. Locations of point shown as `'#'`

```
4 4
##..
#...
...#
....
```

- Output: grid of numbers showing "Manhattan distance" to each nearest point.

```
0 0 1 2
0 1 2 1
1 2 1 0
2 3 2 1
```

To set a lot of numbers into a grid, I used two-dimensional `IOArray` to reduce modification costs. It takes more than a minute to process a grid of 500x500, while an alternative code I wrote in Python just takes within 5 seconds.

Less than 16 seconds would be highly appreciated!

```
import Data.List
import Data.Array.IO
import Control.Monad

type Point = (Int, Int)
type Grid = IOArray Point Int

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [height, width] <- (map read . take 2 . words) <$> getLine
  points <- zeroPoints width <$> getContents
  grid <- newArray ((1,1), (height, width)) (-1)
  wfs grid points 0
  printArray grid

zeroPoints :: Int -> String -> [Point]
zeroPoints width str = [(i `div` width + 1, i `mod` width + 1) | (i, c) <- chars, c == '#']
  where chars = zip [0..] (concat $ words str)

wfs :: Grid -> [Point] -> Int -> IO [Point]
wfs grid [] _ = return []
wfs grid points distance = do
  mapM_ (\p -> writeArray grid p distance) points
  (_, (height, width)) <- getBounds grid
  newPoints <- neighbors grid height width points
  wfs grid newPoints (distance + 1)

neighbors :: Grid -> Int -> Int -> [Point] -> IO [Point]
neighbors grid height width points =
  filterM (isEmpty grid) $ nub $ filter inArea $ [up, down, left, right] <*> points
  where
    up    (x, y) = (x - 1, y)
    down  (x, y) = (x + 1, y)
    left  (x, y) = (x, y - 1)
    right (x, y) = (x, y + 1)
    inArea (x, y) = x > 0 && x <= height && y > 0 && y <= width
    isEmpty grid p = (< 0) <$> readArray grid p

printArray :: Grid -> IO ()
printArray grid = do
  (_, (height, width)) <- getBounds grid
  forM_ [(h, w) | h <- [1..height], w <- [1..width]] $ \(h, w) -> do
    i <- readArray grid (h, w)
    if w == width then putStrLn $ show i else putStr $ show i ++ " "
```

Comment: Unless you have a specific question about the code, this belongs on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't done any profiling, but this is the line that leaps out at me:

```
  filterM (isEmpty grid) $ nub $ filter inArea $ [up, down, left, right] <*> points
```

In particular, `nub` is an O(n^2) operation. You might start by trying to use `ordNub` from `Data.Containers.ListUtils`.

Another thing I see is that you're using *boxed* arrays. Boxed arrays have indirection costs and also extra GC costs; they could easily make code using them several times slower than it should be. As a general rule, you should only use boxed arrays if you need either their polymorphism or their laziness. I don't immediately see any of that here.

Finally, a micro-optimization: If you need both the quotient and the remainder, use `divMod` or `quotRem` to do the job with just one hardware division. That's not why your code is slow, but it's a good habit. If the numbers are positive, use `quotRem` for speed. If they're not, be sure to read the documentation to figure out which you should use.

Comment: Thank you for quick solutions! `nubOrd` saved 30 sec `IOUArray` saved 3 sec in average. In fact previously I ran without compilation, just used `stack runghc ..`. After compilation now it ends in 2 seconds! (with `nub` it still takes about 20 secs)